# How to add a text node to a toast notification

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

This toast notification works very well from the desktop with XE8 With Windows 10, but I can not figure out how to add a text line to the notification.  iTitle is displayed but iMessage is not.  This is all new to me so I do not know which direction to pursue.

**Fifth edit....**

Remy's excellent show toast procedure is a big improvement over the original Embaracdero code, but I don't think Remy actually tested the code because it would not compile as written.  I had to change TWindowString to TWindowsString and IXmlNode to Xml_Dom_IXmlNode to get it to compile.

The following actually compiles but it generates an access violation in the GetActivationFactory function.

If we can get this to function correctly it will be a big improvement over the original Embarcadero code and should be of value to other developers.

```
 procedure TForm1.ShowToast(const AMessage: String; const ATitle: String = '');
{ Send a Toast Notification }
var
  LINotificationManagerStatics: IToastNotificationManagerStatics;
  LToast: IToastNotification;
  LToastFactory: IToastNotificationFactory;
  LToastNotifier: IToastNotifier;
  LToastTemplateType: ToastTemplateType;
  LAccepted: TAcceptedEventHandler;
  LXMLTemplate: Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;
  iTextNode: Xml_Dom_IXmlNode;
  LTextNodeList: Xml_Dom_IXmlNodeList;

  function GetActivationFactory(const ClassId: String; const Iid: String): IInspectable;
  begin
    OleCheck(RoGetActivationFactory(TWindowsString(ClassId), TGUID.Create(Iid), Result));
   // This produces an access violation at run time
  end;

begin
  LINotificationManagerStatics := GetActivationFactory(SToastNotificationManager, '{50AC103F-D235-4598-BBEF-98FE4D1A3AD4}') as IToastNotificationManagerStatics;
  LToastNotifier := LINotificationManagerStatics.CreateToastNotifier(TWindowsString(Edit1.Text));
  if ATitle <> '' then begin
    LToastTemplateType := ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
  end else begin
    LToastTemplateType := ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;
  end;
  LXMLTemplate := LINotificationManagerStatics.GetTemplateContent(LToastTemplateType);
  LTextNodeList := LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(TWindowsString('text'));
  if ATitle <> '' then
  begin
    LTextNodeList.Item(0).AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(TWindowsString(ATitle)) as Xml_Dom_IXmlNode);
    iTextNode := LTextNodeList.Item(1);
  end else begin
    iTextNode := LTextNodeList.Item(0);
  end;
  iTextNode.AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(TWindowsString(AMessage)) as Xml_Dom_IXmlNode);
  LToastFactory := GetActivationFactory(SToastNotification, '{04124B20-82C6-4229-B109-FD9ED4662B53}') as IToastNotificationFactory;
  LToast := LToastFactory.CreateToastNotification(LXMLTemplate);
  LAccepted := TAcceptedEventHandler.Create;
  LToast.add_Activated(LAccepted);
  LToastNotifier.Show(LToast);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging I finally was successful getting the Toast Notification to display a Title and a message.  It turns out I had to use a modified version of Remy's answer in combination with some of the Embaracdero's original demo code to get it to work.

Thank you Remy!  I did not think I was going to get there but I finally did.
To save others who are trying to do this a lot of grief my working code is shown below:

```
procedure TForm1.ShowToast(const AMessage: String; const ATitle: String = '');
{ Send a Toast Notification }
var
  LINotificationManagerStatics: IToastNotificationManagerStatics;
  LToast: IToastNotification;
  LToastFactory: IToastNotificationFactory;
  LToastNotifier: IToastNotifier;
  LClassId: HString;
  LAccepted: TAcceptedEventHandler;
  LXMLTemplate: Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;
  iTextNode: Xml_Dom_IXmlNode;
  LTextNodeList: Xml_Dom_IXmlNodeList;
  LTagName: HString;
  LTitle: HString;
  LMessage: HString;

  function GetActivationFactory(const ClassId: String; const Iid: String)
    : IInspectable;
  begin
    if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(ClassId), Length(ClassId),
      LClassId)) then
      OleCheck(RoGetActivationFactory(LClassId, TGUID.Create(Iid), Result));
  end;

begin
  LINotificationManagerStatics := GetActivationFactory
    (SToastNotificationManager, '{50AC103F-D235-4598-BBEF-98FE4D1A3AD4}')
    as IToastNotificationManagerStatics;
  if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(NotificationTitle1.Text),
    Length(NotificationTitle1.Text), LClassId)) then
    LToastNotifier := LINotificationManagerStatics.CreateToastNotifier
      (LClassId);
  LXMLTemplate := LINotificationManagerStatics.GetTemplateContent
    (ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);
  if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar('text'), Length('text'), LTagName))
  then
    LTextNodeList := LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(LTagName);
  if ATitle <> '' then
  begin
    if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(ATitle), Length(ATitle), LTitle))
    then
      LTextNodeList.Item(0).AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(LTitle)
        as Xml_Dom_IXmlNode);
    iTextNode := LTextNodeList.Item(1);
  end
  else
  begin
    iTextNode := LTextNodeList.Item(0);
  end;
  if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(AMessage), Length(AMessage),
    LMessage)) then
    iTextNode.AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(LMessage)
      as Xml_Dom_IXmlNode);
  LToastFactory := GetActivationFactory(SToastNotification,
    '{04124B20-82C6-4229-B109-FD9ED4662B53}') as IToastNotificationFactory;
  LToast := LToastFactory.CreateToastNotification(LXMLTemplate);
  LAccepted := TAcceptedEventHandler.Create;
  LToast.add_Activated(LAccepted);
  LToastNotifier.Show(LToast);
end;
```

**Usage:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowToast(NotificationMessage1.Text, NotificationTitle1.Text);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

`IXmlDocument.CreateTextNode()` creates and returns a new text node but DOES NOT add it to the XML document.  You have to add it separately.  This is even demonstrated in the Toast documentatation:

[Quickstart: Sending a toast notification (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx)

[Quickstart: Sending a toast notification (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx)

For example:

```
var
  ...
  LTagName: HString;

...    
if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar(iMessage), Length(iMessage), LString3)) then
try
  if Succeeded(WindowsCreateString(PWideChar('text'), 4, LTagName)) then
  try
    LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(LTagName).Item(0).AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(LString3) as IXmlNode);
    ...
  finally
    WindowsDeleteString(LTagName);
  end;
  ...
finally
  WindowsDeleteString(LString3);
end;
...
```

Alternatively, use the `IXmlNode.InnerText` property instead of the `IXmlDocument.CreateTextNode()` method:

```
LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(LTagName).Item(0).InnerText := LString3;
```

Frankly, [Embarcadero's example](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/windows-10-notifications-from-a-vcl-app-with-the-winrt-api), which you based your code on, is a bit of mess.  It could use some serious cleanup.

Try something more like this:

```
uses
  ...,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Win.ComObj,
  Winapi.Data,
  System.WinrtHelpers; // see https://github.com/tgerdes/DelphiWinRT/blob/master/System.WinrtHelpers.pas

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowToast('The recycle bin is empty', 'Recycle Bin Is Empty');
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowToast(const AMessage: String; const ATitle: String = '');
{ Send a Toast Notification }
var
  LINotificationManagerStatics: IToastNotificationManagerStatics;
  LToast: IToastNotification;
  LToastFactory: IToastNotificationFactory;
  LToastNotifier: IToastNotifier;
  LToastTemplateType: ToastTemplateType;
  LAccepted: TAcceptedEventHandler;
  LXMLTemplate: Xml_Dom_IXmlDocument;
  iTextNode: Xml_Dom_IXmlNode;
  LTextNodeList: Xml_Dom_IXmlNodeList;

  function GetActivationFactory(const ClassId: String; const Iid: String): IInspectable;
  begin
    OleCheck(RoGetActivationFactory(TWindowsString(ClassId), TGUID.Create(Iid), Result));
  end;

begin
  LINotificationManagerStatics := GetActivationFactory(SToastNotificationManager, '{50AC103F-D235-4598-BBEF-98FE4D1A3AD4}') as IToastNotificationManagerStatics;
  LToastNotifier := LINotificationManagerStatics.CreateToastNotifier(TWindowString(Edit1.Text));
  if ATitle <> '' then begin
    LToastTemplateType := ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
  end else begin
    LToastTemplateType := ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;
  end;
  LXMLTemplate := LINotificationManagerStatics.GetTemplateContent(LToastTemplateType);
  LTextNodeList := LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(TWindowString('text'));
  if ATitle <> '' then
  begin
    LTextNodeList.Item(0).AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(TWindowString(ATitle)) as IXmlNode);
    iTextNode := LTextNodeList.Item(1);
  end else begin
    iTextNode := LTextNodeList.Item(0);
  end;
  iTextNode.AppendChild(LXMLTemplate.CreateTextNode(TWindowString(AMessage)) as IXmlNode);
  LToastFactory := GetActivationFactory(SToastNotification, '{04124B20-82C6-4229-B109-FD9ED4662B53}') as IToastNotificationFactory;
  LToast := LToastFactory.CreateToastNotification(LXMLTemplate);
  LAccepted := TAcceptedEventHandler.Create;
  LToast.add_Activated(LAccepted);
  LToastNotifier.Show(LToast);
end;
```

Comment: Neither way compiles with XE8?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: See my dcc32 error added to your post.  Apparently it does not like 'text'... because that is where the pointer is after the error.  I tried breaking the statement down into its component parts to try to resolve but I have not been successful yet.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer to include the compiler errors. I have rejected that edit. Please edit your original question instead to show the updated code you have tried and the errors it is reporting.

Comment: Obviously, you will have to call `WindowsCreateString()` to convert `string` values to `HString` when calling `getElementsByTagNames()`, since that is what the compiler is complaining about. Did you try that yet?

Comment: Yes but none of the parameters as you wrote them will compile... see edit

Comment: Boy this is difficult to deal with compared with what I am used to dealing with... all just to add one line of text to a notification.... there must be an easier way...

Comment: Notice that  LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(LTagname).Item[0]. will not compile but  LXMLTemplate.getElementsByTagName(LTagname).Item(0). compiles

Comment: see my comments in the new edit.  I appreciate your efforts for sure!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87516/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-bill).