# Change Attribution Area in Toast Notification in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, notifications, windows-10, toast

How to change icon near Application Name in Attribution Area in Toast Notification?
I'm using code similar to [How to add a text node to a toast notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105337/how-to-add-a-text-node-to-a-toast-notification). Code under link helps change Application Name.

I can change placement images like appLogoOverride, hero or inline, but can not change (main) icon in Attribution area.

Windows 10, Delphi Seattle.

Answer (score 0):

For me the *icon* and *app name* on the Attribution area could be changed on the Application settings, when opening the Properties of the project in Visual Studio.

[image]

On this menu, the *icon* can be changed by browsing your image, and the *app name* matches the Assembly Name (see also Assembly Information to make sure everything matches).